# construct two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A| = C$, $|B| = \aleph_0$, but the intersection is finite

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm kinda confuse on how I'm suppose to this.

I know  $\aleph_0$ is inifinite.

For $B$ I assumed since it was $|B| = \aleph_0$ it would be

$$B = \{ 1,2,3,4, \dots \}$$

and for $A$ since $C$ seems to be some random integer I just assumed another integer $4$, so for $A$ I simply did

$$A = \{1,2,3,4 \}.$$

Comment: Are you sure the question doesn't mean $\mathfrak c$, the cardinality of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: You just construct two sets disjoint to each other.

Answer (score 3):

Q and R\Q have the property of problem